# Fluent Validation only if value is supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I have a Post method and based on the data Posted I will return a result. I want to perform validation only if the fields are supplied. If no value is posted I do not want to perform the validation. This is what I have currently. Obviously if the value is null it will crash as it expects a value, how can I solve this?

```
public bool IsValidAvailability(int AvailabiltyValue)
{
    if (AvailabiltyValue > AvailabilityMax || AvailabiltyValue < AvailabilityMin)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

This is my Rules for the validation. Can I add anything to make this validation below happen only if the value is supplied?

```
RuleFor(x => (int)x.Availability).Must(validatorServices.IsValidAvailability).WithMessage("Availability must be between " + validatorServices.AvailabilityMin + " and " + validatorServices.AvailabilityMax);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that through the usage of `When` and `Unless` methods.

The `When` and `Unless` methods can be used to specify conditions that control when the rule should execute. For example, this rule on the `CustomerDiscount` property will only execute when `IsPreferredCustomer` is `true`:

```
RuleFor(customer => customer.CustomerDiscount)
   .GreaterThan(0)
   .When(customer => customer.IsPreferredCustomer);
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#user-content-specifying-a-condition-with-whenunless).